# DatePicker no Characters allowed

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

Short Question, is it possible to disable Characters Entry in a DataPicker so that the User is just allowed to enter numbers and dots and slashes?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewTextInput` event of the `DatePicker` something like this:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dp" PreviewTextInput="DatePicker_TextChanged" />
```

---

```
Private Sub DatePicker_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs)
    If Not (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(e.Text) Or e.Text = "." Or e.Text = "/" Or e.Text = "\") Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

> Is there anyway to do this  in Code behind?

Sure. Try this:

```
AddHandler dp.PreviewTextInput, AddressOf DatePicker_TextChanged
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it later this day and will answer here if it worked or not :)

Comment: Is there anyway to do this `<DatePicker PreviewTextInput="DatePicker_TextChanged" />` in Code behind? The Problem is that the DatePicker and the Textboxes are created automatically from Parameters in the SQL DataBase.

Comment: Found it. Nevermind. Seems to work! Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do it yourself :

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"/>

private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if(!is_number(e.Text) && !is_dot(e.Text) && ...)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Setting e.Handled = true intercepts the event and prevents the action to take place.
I would recommend using a regex instead of is_number etc... (I'm sure there are plenty of examples of regexes out there).

Note that this will not work with spacebar, you will have to use the previewkeydown event for that, and there might be some other keys that are not treated in PreviewTextInput and that would modify your Text, but I can not think of any.

#### EDIT :

I just saw you use VB, the code I posted is for C#, I don't know any VB but I imagine it shouldn't be that different.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to translate it into VB and going to try it.